# How to stop downvotes on it?

Tags: discussion

I don't know why I personally like this question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/54338/whats-the-position-of-stark-industries-in-business-world

But, everyones tastes aren't same. I am getting downvotes. How to stop that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why am I getting too many downvotes on my posts?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2136/why-am-i-getting-too-many-downvotes-on-my-posts)

Comment: @phantom42 There'll be a lie detector machine. You know where...

Comment: @phantom42 - It's kind of a dupe, but OP is asking why this specific question is getting downvotes, not what causes downvotes in general

Comment: It's definitely a dupe. Both questions are asked by the OP, and both address the general point of question quality.

Answer (score 9):

Rather than ask "how do I stop downvotes", ask instead "why is this question receiving downvotes". The only way to stop downvotes is to ask questions that people think are goodd, so focus on *improving* the question. That's probably what you meant, but I just wanted to make this explicit.

The biggest problem I can see with your question is that it's unclear. Your basic question seems to be "How successful is Stark Industries in the Marvel Universe's economy", but then you muddle the issue with questions about arms companies, quotes about bailouts from sources that seem far from credible, and then a *different* question about the economic *history* of Stark Industries.

My suggestion is to tighten up the question, decide what exactly it is you're asking (for instance "Is Stark Industries a Forbes 25 company? How does this make sense considering that arms companies seldom make that list in the real world" is one. "What economic booms and downturns has Stark Industries undergone over the years, and why?" could be another) and focus on that, and drop the "bailout" quote unless it directly refers to the question asked ("if it *isn't* a Forbes 25 company, how come Tony Stark claims that he didn't need a bailout?").

Comment: +1 for "stop downvotes by improving the question".  It is of course useful if downvoters help you by telling you why they downvoted in a comment.

Answer (score 3):

I flagged this as "unclear what you're asking" for a few of reasons;

1) There's at least 4 questions here;

- Is Stark Industries is Forbes 25 company?
- Did Stark Industries face bankuptcy
- What is their current financial position?
- **Can you give me a complete list of all mentions of Starks' financial status in the various comics and films?**

The first 3 questions are (potentially) quite easy to answer whereas the last question would require weeks of research. That alone was sufficient to get me to flag it.

There were a couple of other things you might want to address;

2) You've started with a fairly strong contention that they **can't be** a Forbes 25 company because they make weapons. I'm not sure what that adds to the debate but it certainly put me off answering since you seem to have prejudged the results.

3) The language and formatting you've used is very haphazard. You've basically asked and answered your own questions as you've gone along. Try to make your questions more singular and avoid unnecessary "chattiness".

Comment: That is not what 2) says.  Sachin said that the current Forbes Top 50 does not include companies that sell weapons, and was asking for confirmation by way of "Is Stark Industries a Forbes 25 company?"

Comment: @Izkata - The fact that that's not clear should be warning enough that the question is poorly phrased